# Binary search over 2d array to find a local maximum? What's wrong with this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search, discrete-mathematics

This is the classic finding a local maximum (just one) in a matrix.

My algorithm is:

- Choose the number in the center of the matrix.
- Check if the number is a peak. If yes, return.
- If not, check the numbers to the left and right. If one of them is greater than our current number, choose that half of the matrix. If both are greater, we can choose either half.
- Repeat with the numbers to the top and bottom. This will leave us with one quadrant of the matrix to continue checking.

Since this is binary search for a n x n matrix which has n^2 elements, it should take O(log(n^2)) = O(2*log(n)) = O(log(n))

I'm pretty sure this is not correct, but where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you uncertain about the complexity or the algorithm? Maybe you should look at this- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-peak-element-2d-array/

Comment: One of the pre-condition for binary search to be applied is that the data is sorted...first of all is your 2D matrix is sorted in some order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm isn't guaranteed to find the local maximum. Consider for example the case where you need to follow a winding path through the matrix of ascending values to get to the peak. If that path crosses back and forth between quadrants you algorithm will not find it.

```
13  1  1  1  1
12  1  1  1  1
11  1  1  2  3
10  1  1  1  4
 9  8  7  6  5
```

Or, here's a simpler example:

```
3  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
```

You start in the middle, how do you find the '3'?  You algorithm doesn't describe what to do when faced with a horizontal plane.

Comment: Nice answer, I posted one extending yours, I believe. Take a look please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading [Find a peak element in a 2D array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-peak-element-2d-array/), where it describes a brute force approach, as well as an efficient method which has a time complexity of `O(rows * log(columns))`, in yout case `O(nlogn)`.

The algorithm is based on Binary Search, thus the `logn` term you had in your complexity too:

1. Consider mid column and find maximum element in it.
2. Let index of mid column be ‘mid’, value of maximum element in mid
   column be ‘max’ and maximum element be at ‘mat[max_index][mid]’.
3. If max >= A[index][mid-1] & max >= A[index][pick+1], max is a peak,
   return max.
4. If max < mat[max_index][mid-1], recur for left half of matrix.
5. If max < mat[max_index][mid+1], recur for right half of matrix.

---

However, *your* algorithm won't work for all cases, and might fail to find a local maximum, since you only look neighboring elements of the current center, which does not guarantee you that will find the maximum (the elements are not sorted of course). Example:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 10
```

You start from the center, you pick the wrong submatrix, you are doomed not to find the local maximum.